# Is it possible to filter address based upon 360 degree geolocation area?

Tags: javascript, html, filter, geolocation, street-address

I am currently looking to provide a feature on my developing website that will enable user/visitors to see whether there specific address is within the unique service area of my business.

If so allowing them to proceed further or if not plug them into an update newsletter of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do this, here is an example of doing something similar using the Google Maps API

[poly-containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation)

You would need to geocode the customer address, and determine what your boundaries are for your polygon then pass the address latitude and longitude to the poly.containsLocation function.